# Custom UITableViewCell delegate pattern in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, swift

I have a weird problem in a Swift + Objective-C problem.

I'm implementing a UITableView and a custom cell with a delegate in swift, but as soon as my UITableViewController assign my cell delegate to self, it crash both my app and Xcode.
Yeah each time I crash my app, Xcode crash too, no matter what, but this is another problem.

Here is a part of my cell

```
enum NewsCellActionType: Int {  
    case Vote = 0
    case Comments
    case Time
}

protocol NewsCellDelegate {
    func newsCellDidSelectButton(cell: NewsCell, actionType: NewsCellActionType)
}

class NewsCell: UITableViewCell {



    var cellDelegate: NewsCellDelegate?

 func selectedAction(action: NewsCellActionType) {
        self.cellDelegate?.newsCellDidSelectButton(self, actionType: action)
    }
}
```

And here is where I set the delegate in my UIViewController

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(NewsCellsId) as NewsCell
        if cell == nil {
            cell = NewsCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: NewsCellsId)
        }
        cell.post = self.posts[indexPath.row] as HNPost
        cell.cellDelegate = self
        return cell

    }
```

It crash at the line cell.cellDelegate = self, I have no idea why. Is it a bug in the current DP, or am I doing it wrong?

I tried to use weak on my delegate var + the @objc tag on the protocol, but as I use a pure Swift enum I can't do that. But do I need it?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your self confirming 'NewsCellDelegate' protocol???

Comment: Of course, but I think it's because my protocol is in swift only, and my class interface with objective-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022763/uitableview-in-swift)

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of an already answered question, I guess. The problem with `as` vs `as?`.

Comment: No sorry, it's about delegate and crash. Not about UITableViewCell. This is for example only.

Comment: Does it crash when you comment out the delegate assignment?

Comment: @Sulthan hop, if I comment the assignment it doesn't crash

Comment: Well, I am not able to reproduce it. Could you extract a snippet that reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Sulthan Well you can clone and pod install my repo here: https://github.com/Dimillian/SwiftHN It contains this code, it should crash in the last commit.

Answer (score 4):

I needed two changes to make your code work

<del>1. replaced `as` with `as?` after `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`</del>

<del>(see [UITableView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022763/uitableview-in-swift) for more details)</del>

The first change not needed because the cell can't be `nil` (storyboard ensures it). I have built the code wrong.

2. Added `@class_protocol` to the `NewsCellDelegate`

```
@class_protocol protocol NewsCellDelegate {
```

I am not really sure why the app crashes without it and I think it's a bug. However, `@class_protocol` should be used anyway because we should declare the `cellDelegate` as `weak` and without `@class_protocol` we can't do it.

```
weak var cellDelegate: NewsCellDelegate?
```

Unfortunately, adding `weak` makes the app crash when the delegate is used.

There is an enourmous number of memory leaks in your code, starting with the library, which is written with ARC but it is set as MRC.

Your closures in `NewsCell` are capturing `self`, creating retain cycles (and subsequently leaked cells).

I wasn't able to find the reason of the crash but I am pretty sure it's a bug in the compiler/runtime because it is not only crashing the app, but also Xcode and 3 times it even crashed my system.

Comment: I feel it's a bug because not only the app was crashing, my whole Xcode was crashing.

Comment: You're right for the first part, totally a Swift issue on my side. Fir the second part, the delegate assignation now work, but whenever the delegate is called, it still crash the app and Xcode (try to click on the orange buttons under the cell title). EDIT: Ok saw your edit!

Comment: Same here. xCode crashes on every turn. Intellisense is awful. Takes time for it to identify new variables. Ok.. it's still demo.

Answer (score 4):

Here I posted the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24145675/1091145).

> Currently you have to explicitly mark your protocols with @objc if the delegate should be an Object of a Objective-C class (Like the UITableViewController):

```
@objc protocol SwiftProtocol
```

This will enable interoperating with Objective-C

Comment: So too bad I won't be able to use the nice new enum out of the box right?

Comment: In fact you will.
You can subclass Objective-C classes and enhance them with the use of Swift's language features.

Answer (score 2):

protocol NewsCellDelegate:class {
    func newsCellDidSelectButton(cell: NewsCell, actionType: NewsCellActionType)
}

you're missing a "class"

Comment: This was the issue for me; do you have a reference link that explains this further ?