# How to pass swift enum with @objc tag

Tags: ios, enums, swift

I need to define a protocol which can be called in a class that use some Objective-c type

But doing that doesn't work:

```
enum NewsCellActionType: Int {
    case Vote = 0
    case Comments
    case Time
}

@objc protocol NewsCellDelegate {
    func newsCellDidSelectButton(cell: NewsCell, actionType: NewsCellActionType)
}
```

You get he error

```
Swift enums cannot be represented in Objective-C
```

If I don't put the @objc tag on my protocol it'll crash the app as soon as it's called in a class which adopt the protocol AND inherit from an Objective-C type class (like a UIViewController).

So my question is, how should I declare and pass my enum with the @objc tag?

Comment: See my answer. I am pretty sure your problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Swift enums are very different from Obj-C (or C) enums and they can't be passed directly to Obj-C.

As a workaround, you can declare your method with an `Int` parameter.

```
func newsCellDidSelectButton(cell: NewsCell, actionType: Int)
```

and pass it as `NewsCellActionType.Vote.toRaw()`. You won't be able to access the enum names from Obj-C though and it makes the code much more difficult.

A better solution might be to implement the enum in Obj-C (for example, in your briding header) because then it will be automatically accessible in Swift and it will be possible to pass it as a parameter.

**EDIT**

It is not required to add `@objc` simply to use it for an Obj-C class. If your code is pure Swift, you can use enums without problems, see the following example as a proof:

```
enum NewsCellActionType : Int {
    case Vote = 0
    case Comments
    case Time
}

protocol NewsCellDelegate {
    func newsCellDidSelectButton(cell: UITableViewCell?, actionType: NewsCellActionType    )
}

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, NewsCellDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

        self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

        test()

        return true;
    }

    func newsCellDidSelectButton(cell: UITableViewCell?, actionType: NewsCellActionType) {
        println(actionType.toRaw());
    }

    func test() {
        self.newsCellDidSelectButton(nil, actionType: NewsCellActionType.Vote)
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, my code is pure swift, but it crash, related to my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137090/custom-uitableviewcell-delegate-pattern-in-swift

Comment: You should have left your edit, your question answer mine perfectly, but as you stated, my code is pure Swift. I assumed the crash was because I don't prefixed it with the @objc tag. But sound like I'm wrong.

Comment: @Dimillian77 Sorry, I did an invalid edit and had to write it again.

Comment: Unless of course you require optional values for your protocol... Highly irritating... oh well.

Answer (score 63):

Apple just announced today that Swift 1.2 (included with xcode 6.3) will support exposing enums to objective-c

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/

[image]

Comment: For info: This appears to apply only to enums of type Int.  Applying @objc to an enum of type String yields the following compilation error: "'@objc' enum raw type 'String' is not an integer type."

Comment: objc (and many other languages) only support enums in ints. swift is unique in this regard

Comment: Didn't work in Swift 2.0. Swift ENUM was not visible in ObjC

Comment: Make sure your enum is of type Int and marked as @objc like the example above

Comment: It has to be `Int` type that inherits from, because of the obj-c / c enum type representation is different to Swift.