# Check protocol conformance when protocol contains an enum in Swift?

Tags: enums, swift, protocols

In Swift, in order to check protocol conformance with `is` or `as?` downcasting you must mark the protocol with the `@objc` attribute.  Once you mark a protocol with that attribute it seems you can not have a protocol with an enum as a property because enums cannot be represented in Objective-C.

```
enum Language:String {
    case English = "English"
    case Spanish = "Spanish"
    case German = "German"
}

@objc protocol Humanizable {
    var language:Language { get set }
}
```

You'll get an error: `error: property cannot be marked @objc because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C`

Here is full example: http://swiftstub.com/475659213/

In the example if you change the `Language` to `String` then it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the swiftstub.com link, very useful! An interesting problem too.

Comment: @Graff No prob. At least you can try it out and see the issue I am facing.

Comment: Yep, I see it. I fooled around a bit but haven't come up with anything yet. Hopefully there's a good answer out there, the most I could come up with was using an Int or String in place of the enum.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass swift enum with @objc tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140545/how-to-pass-swift-enum-with-objc-tag)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but I did spot a compile error in your 'swift stub', `Human` should be defined as follows:

```
class Human:Humanizable {
  var name:String = "Frank"
  var language:Language = .English
}
```

You were trying to create an enum instance from a string literal.

I am a little surprised that protocol conformance checking requires `@obj` - that's just ugly!

Comment: Yah it's weird: “You can check for protocol conformance only if your protocol is marked with the @objc attribute” Straight from the iBook.